# Deploy on Windows Phone 7 in App Hub unsupported country

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, deployment, xap

I would like to debug and deploy the application on the Windows Phone 7 device in order to test and debug it. But to do that I need to register my phone(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769512%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and for that I need to be registered as a developer on App Hub (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769508%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), but my country is not on the list of supported countries yet.

So just to start to play with the OS and deploy on device development I need to wait? Here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh286410%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) is mentioned the APPA market – would this be a way to register and get the phone being registered as a developer phone?

Thanks a lot
Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as you mentioned, the way to publish from (and test in) countries which are not currently supported by the App Hub or Marketplace is via the [Global Publisher Program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh286410%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: I have used the APPA Market, it costs 25GBP for every phone unlock and they need access via Team Viewer to my computer, but it is a temporary solution until market is available in all countries...